# lsp-mode: disable documentation popup

Tags: lsp-mode, rust

I installed rustic-mode with LSP server. They work. But now it shows docs and description of every symbol I put my cursor on. It distracts and irritates me a lot. How can I make it show the symbol info and docs on demand only when I click a certain key? I tried this:

```
(setq lsp-eldoc-render-all nil)
(setq lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting nil)
(setq lsp-eldoc-render-all nil)
(setq lsp-signature-render-documentation nil)
```

But only what I got so far is this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following.

```
(setq lsp-ui-doc-enable nil
      lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil)
```

You can check how to set/reset the options from the [LSP page](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/how-to-turn-off/).

Comment: Do you know, what functions to call to get the docs / symbol info on demand?

Comment: You can try `lsp-ui-doc-mode` and `lsp-ui-doc-glance`.